# Conditions of a quasiconvex codimension 1 subgroup of a hyperbolic group that determine it to be a surface subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, surfaces

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is called quasiconvex if in the Cayley graph of $G$, $\Gamma (G,S)$,  there exists $k>0$ such that all geodesics that join a pair of points in $H$ are subsets of a $k$-neighbourhood of $H$.
A subgroup $H$ of $G$ has codimension 1 if $H \backslash \Gamma - \Lambda$ has 2 or more infinite components for some compact subgraph $\Lambda $ of the coset graph $H \backslash \Gamma $.

Is it known what conditions (necessary and/or sufficient) of a quasiconvex codimension 1 subgroup of a hyperbolic group determine it to be a surface subgroup?

Comment: Its limit set should be homeomorphic to a circle. Do you want an algebraic or geometric criterion? Do you have an application in mind?